# Moment JS getting Date without time

Tags: datetime, momentjs

I don't need formatted string from `moment()` without time.
Like this is not suitable:

```
moment().format('M/D/Y')
```

I need to get the `Date()` without time, just date with 00:00:00 time.
I could create Date() adding `now.year() + now.month() + now.day()`
but this is ugly.
Need help